# How do I do a transacted receive in a Message Driven Bean in Java EE 6?

Tags: java, transactions, jms

*Sending* a transacted message from an MDB or other code is documented all over the web.

But how do you do a transacted *receive* with an MDB? The documentation that I've come across suggests that, much like a transacted send, you'll need to call `Session.commit()` to confirm reception of the message.

However, I can't figure out how to access the (JMS) session instance! It doesn't seem to be available via the `MessageDrivenContext` instance.

Also, I need to use BMT (bean managed transactions) in my MDB in order to control race-conditions involving the `afterCompletion` method of a `javax.transaction.Synchronization` instance. Being able to do a transacted receive would be nicer than throwing a (runtime) exception from `onMessage(Message)`.

Comment: So, I found a solution for this, but apparently most people disagree with my solution so I've removed it.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a bit wrong understanding of the topic here.

MDB could be used in BMT mode but then `onMessage` receives a message without the transaction in auto ack mode. That means message is received and later on you can start you own transaction where you send a message to a queue. If it's rolled back the message received by `onMessage` is not "returned" back to receiving queue but it's just lost.

MDB permits for CMT being used transaction attributes `REQUIRED` and `NOT_SUPPORTED` ([ejb 3.2 spec: 5.4.13 Transaction Context of Message-Driven Bean Methods](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr345/index.html)). `REQUIRED` does what you expect - it joins `onMessage` receive and your actions in `onMessage` method under one global transaction. Which if fails it returns message back to the receive queue and could be received by MDB once again. When `NOT_SUPPORTED` is used then message at receive is auto acked and method runs with no active transaction context.

If you want to use transaction synchronization then you are expected to use `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`. Or in case add JTA [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Synchronization.html) with usage of [TransactionManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html).